# Auto set Woocommerce product to draft status if order is completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

In WooCommerce I would like to set products to draft status when Order is completed… So what I want is to make products to be sold 1 time and passed to draft when order get completed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, that will set the products found in order items with a "draft" status only when order get "processing" or "completed" statuses *(paid order statuses)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'action_order_status_changed', 10, 4 );
function action_order_status_changed( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    // Only for processing and completed orders
    if( ! ( $new_status == 'processing' || $new_status == 'completed' ) )
        return; // Exit

    // Checking if the action has already been done before
    if( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_products_to_draft', true ) )
        return; // Exit
        
    $products_set_to_draft = false; // Initializing variable 

    // Loop through order items
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object instance
        if ('draft' != $product->get_status() ){
            $product->set_status('draft'); // Set status to draft
            $product->save(); // Save the product
            $products_set_to_draft = true;
        }
    }
    // Mark the action done for this order (to avoid repetitions)
    if($products_set_to_draft)
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_products_to_draft', '1' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> If you want **to target only "completed" orders**, you can replace this line:
>
> ```
>   if( ! ( $new_status == 'processing' || $new_status == 'completed' ) )
> ```
>
> by this one:
>
> ```
>   if( $new_status != 'completed' )
> ```