# Set a variable product to draft if a specific variation is purchased in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

I have looked at this solution, but it is not completely covering our situation. [Auto set Woocommerce product to draft status if order is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172698/auto-set-woocommerce-product-to-draft-status-if-order-is-completed).

I am trying to target specific product variations that have the product attribute taxonomy "pa_type" with a Term name that is "Exclusive purchase". Then if that variation is purchased the parent variable product status must be set to draft.

Comment: Please explain:  "it is not completely covering our situation" . To what situation are you referring?

Comment: @Jamie_D, the situation as described in the link is not checking a specific variation as other variations can also have stock

Comment: Do you know "in advance" what the specific "Variation ID"  is?

Comment: @Jamie_D /wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=pa_type&tag_ID=133&post_type=product and within the product I guess it is: <input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[0]" value="303967">

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Jamie_D not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** To handle only a specific product variation with a product attribute taxonomy **`pa_type`** that has the term name **"`Exclusive purchase`"** that will set the parent variable product post status to"draft", use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'paid_order_statuses_set_variable_product_to_draft', 10, 4 );
function paid_order_statuses_set_variable_product_to_draft( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    // Only for processing and completed orders
    if( ! ( $new_status == 'processing' || $new_status == 'completed' ) )
        return; // Exit

    // Checking if the action has already been done before
    if( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_products_to_draft', true ) )
        return; // Exit

    $products_set_to_draft = false; // Initializing variable 

    // Loop through order items
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        // Get the current WC_Product object instance
        $product = $item->get_product(); 

        // Targetting a specific product variations ( Taxonomy: 'pa_type' | term name: 'Exclusive purchase' )
        if( $product->is_type('variation') && $product->get_attribute('pa_type') == 'Exclusive purchase' ){
            // Get the parent variable product instance object
            $parent_product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );

            if ('draft' != $parent_product->get_status() ) {
                $product->set_status('draft'); // Set status to draft
                $product->save(); // Save the product
                $products_set_to_draft = true;
            }
        }
    }
    // Mark the action done for this order (to avoid repetitions)
    if($products_set_to_draft)
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_products_to_draft', '1' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.